# magnitude squared coherence in matlab

Tags: frequency-analysis

I am tring to get magnitud squared coherence (MSC) and I am finding some problems.
In theory, the MSC is the result of the crospectra of two signals, devided by the autospectra of each signal.

Therefore, this is my code:

```
Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency                    
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period       
L = length(myData(1,:)); % length of segment

Hz = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;  % frequency vector 


dat1 = fft(myData(1,:));
dat2 = fft(myData(2,:));

pow1 = dat1.*conj(dat1); % autospectra signal 1 
pow2 = dat2.*conj(dat2); % autospectra signal 2 

cpow = abs(dat1.*conj(dat2)).^2; % crosspectra

coh = cpow./(pow1.*pow2); % getting the coherence


coherence = coh(1:L/2+1);
coherence(2:end-1) = coherence(2:end-1); % adjusting length to Nyquest                 freq


figure;
plot(Hz,coherence)
```

but the result are only "1" and it does not make much seance, so there must be I mistake but I just can't find it.

Thanks for your help